# Trying to set background color of UISearchController in Swift 5

Tags: swift, search, uisearchcontroller, searchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I am trying to set the background color of a UISearchController in Swift 5.

I have tried methods mentioned in other threads but I believe they are outdated.

```
    searchController.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Error Message: Value of type 'UISearchController' has no member 'barTintColor'

Comment: It is unclear what UI element inside `UISearchController` you want to change the background color? Its view? navigationBar? searchBar?

Comment: What does `barTintColor` have to do with background color?

Comment: Try this searchController.view.backgroundColor = .red

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I want to change the color of the searchBar (not the white space where text is entered but the surrounding default gray). It's not the view that I want to change the color of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
```

i.e
if your searchBarStyle is .minimal, you won’t be able to change the barTintColor. It will remain white.